# MsGraph get latest deltaToken

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, graph-api-explorer

Is is possible to get latest dalta link for messages and do not iterate through all messages until we reach last page?
**/v1.0/me/mailFolders/{folderId}/messages/delta** API

From documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-overview  "Resources stored in Azure Active Directory (such as users and groups) support "sync from now" scenarios. This allows you to skip steps 1 and 2 (if you're not interested in retrieving the full state of the resource) and ask for the latest deltaLink instead. Append $deltaToken=latest to the delta function and the response will contain a deltaLink and no resource data."

But that does not work for messages how i understood. Is there another way to do this?